# Cómo hago para seleccionar solo un checkbox por cada tabla que tengo

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Estoy intentando seleccionar **solo un checkbox por cada tabla**...Me ayudan por favor a descubrir la forma de como lo podría hacer. Se los agradecería un montón.
Quiero capturar un checkbox de la tabla_pedidos y otro checkbox de la tabla_ayudantes.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Tipo de Entrega</th>
            <th>Nº Mesa</th>
            <th>Ayudante de Cocina</th>
            <th>Hora Ingreso</th>
            <th>Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabla_pedidos">
        <tr>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>Local</td>
            <td>MESA 7</td>
            <td>Mirko Suarez Suice</td>
            <td>15:40:58</td>
            <td><input id='pedido2' type='checkbox' Onclick='pedido(2)'>Seleccionar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>Local</td>
            <td>MESA 7</td>
            <td>Freddy Vega Espinoza</td>
            <td>15:40:58</td>
            <td><input id='pedido2' type='checkbox' Onclick='pedido(2)'>Seleccionar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Platos Encargados</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabla_ayudantes">
        <tr>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>2 Platos</td>
            <td>Alfredo Benavides Contreras</td>
            <td><input id='mozo60' type='checkbox' Onclick='ayudante(60)'>Seleccionar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>5 Platos</td>
            <td>Carlos Torres Wuong</td>
            <td><input id='mozo61' type='checkbox' Onclick='ayudante(61)'>Seleccionar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo intente con jquery, pero solo me dejaba seleccionar un checkbox entre las dos tablas y yo quiero un checkbox por cada tabla.

Comment: Saludos. Por el comportamiento que mencionas lo que debes usar son **radio** no **checkbox**; con ello, a los **radio** de cada tabla le pones el mismo **name** y distinto **id**; desde luego cuidando el mismo **name** no este en ambas tablas (o no más de una; así como el **id**).

Comment: Hola Ronaldo lo que dice Roberto es cierto aquí un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941631/radio-button-inside-table/32941720